# How to find moving average/max/min of specific period in an array in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, moving-average

I have a google sheet with following data. I have to find moving average of 14(any period) period. It can be found by copy and pasting average function But I want to find it in an array.

Anyone's help is appreciated.

[image: screenshot of data]

Answer (score 0):

### avg:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(ROW(A1:A), 
 QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(ROW(A1:A)&"×"&ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(
 SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(ROW(A1:A)<=TRANSPOSE(ROW(A1:A))=TRUE, 
 TRANSPOSE(A1:A*1)&"×", )),,9^9)), "×"), 9^9, 14 +N("14 day window"))), "×"),
 "select Col1,avg(Col2)
  where Col2 is not null
  group by Col1"), 2, )))
```

[image]

### max:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(ROW(A1:A), 
 QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(ROW(A1:A)&"×"&ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(
 SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(ROW(A1:A)<=TRANSPOSE(ROW(A1:A))=TRUE, 
 TRANSPOSE(A1:A)&"×", )),,9^9)), "×"), 9^9, 14 +N("14 day window"))), "×"),
 "select Col1,max(Col2)
  where Col2 is not null
  group by Col1"), 2, )))
```

### min:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(ROW(A1:A), 
 QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(ROW(A1:A)&"×"&ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(
 SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(ROW(A1:A)<=TRANSPOSE(ROW(A1:A))=TRUE, 
 TRANSPOSE(A1:A)&"×", )),,9^9)), "×"), 9^9, 14 +N("14 day window"))), "×"),
 "select Col1,min(Col2)
  where Col2 is not null
  group by Col1"), 2, )))
```

Comment: its showing value error for avg and max and min not working as expected. please see the screenshot

Comment: @GopalPradhan can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: I'm new here. How to share sheet.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ey1nDcL6HxuoS749ZG5h0uxJuErigT0X_bDOJn2pY5g/edit#gid=1456837612

Comment: @GopalPradhan answer updated. see your sheet

Comment: I have added new functionality in my old sheet. I want a array formula for that. I would be grateful if you could help me out.

Comment: could you please help me to solve my issue

Answer (score 0):

This is a simpler approach that might work for you:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(A2:A="","",(sumif(row(A2:A),"<"&row(A2:A)+14,A2:A)-sumif(row(A2:A),"<"&row(A2:A),A2:A))
/countifs(row(A2:A),">="&row(A2:A),row(A2:A),"<"&row(A2:A)+14,A2:A,"<>")))
```

[image]

The running average uses a diminishing range at the end of the data.

Comment: Thanks a lot. How to find Max and Min?

Comment: There is no simple way to do it - you have to use a similar method to @player0, which involves implicitly creating a 2D array.